# Launching a new command window from Golang in Windows

Tags: windows, go

I'm writing a go application that just uses the command window (CMD) for user input and output. I need to launch another instance of the application that is using its own window.

I trying to use the "os/exec" package but that only creates a window for GUI apps. I tried executing the application with `cmd /c ___` but it still hasn't created a separate window.

Is there a way to launch a non-GUI application with its own window, stdin and stdout?

Answer (score 15):

I found it!

The trick is to use the "start" as a command after `cmd /c`

Here's the code:

`cmd:= exec.Command("cmd","/C","start",_path_to_executable_)
err=cmd.Start()`

Comment: You can actually mark your own questions as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without an intermediary `cmd`, it's also possible by modifying the [process creation flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags):

```golang
import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)
const (
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x10
)
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Cmd{Path: "c:\\windows\\system32\\wsl.exe",
        Args: []string{"-e", "sudo", "aptitude"},
        SysProcAttr: &syscall.SysProcAttr{
            CreationFlags:    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            NoInheritHandles: true,
        },
    }
    err := cmd.Run()
    log.Print(err)
}
```

`NoInheritHandles` lets the window have its own stdin and stdout.